# Returning a function from a function and why brackets are omitted?

Tags: function, go, return-value

I am currently in UCI Go Lang Course and Came across this function which the Syntax I did not understand. The function is directly from the example code, but has a syntax error I do not understand line 2 bracket. Also I come from JS, and C and Why in go are some functions declared without outer brackets?

```
 func MakeDistOrigin(o_x, o_y float64)
            func (float64, float64) float64 {
   fn := func (x, y float64) float64 {
            return math.Sqrt(math.Pow(x - o_x, 2) + 
                      math.Pow(y - o_y, 2))
         }
   return fn
    }
```

I expected this function to have outer brackets for each function and to return a function that then takes in another variable. Thanks!

Comment: Start of with the Tour of Go. And get used to how Go code is formatted.

Answer (score 2):

If you got a syntax error, probably you have a newline after `func MakeDistOrigin(o_x, o_y float64)`. Move the  `func (float64, float64) float64 {` to the same line as the `MakeDistOrigin` declaration, and it should be good.

The second line in the code you pasted is not a function declaration. It is the return type of MakeDistOrigin. Look at it this way:

```
func MakeDistOrigin(o_x, o_y float64) T {
}
```

In the above declaration, `T` is the following type:

```
func (float64, float64) float64
```

So in fact you can simplify this declaration by:

```
type T func (float64, float64) float64 

func MakeDistOrigin(o_x, o_y float64) T {
}
```

So MakeDistOrigin is a function that returns a function of type T, which is a function that gets two float64 values and returns a float64 value.

Inside MakeDistOrigin, a variable `fn` is declared. This variable is of type `T` as well, that is a function that takes two float64s and returns one.

The variable `fn` is initialized with the function definition given next to it, which is, again, a function of type `T`.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I ended up solving the algorithm and it was the newline indeeed. Very new with go, and the tour of Go did not quite fill it in as well as the above paragraph. I was down voted 3 times  for asking. which puts me at a score of 14 so I cant up vote your answer or I would. Thanks again